# Ckeditor + PaperClip images as email attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ckeditor, paperclip

I am using ckeditor and paperclip to compose emails with images. When I upload an image to my server, the images are inserted as :

`<img alt="" src="/ckeditor_assets/pictures/1/content_screenshot_from_2013-02-08_15_50_16.png" style="height:436px; width:800px" />`

IF I send the message as it is will the recipient be able to see the images? 
I dont think my server would be visible on the internet.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The images will not show because the urls are relative. You can simply make the urls absolute and they will be found and rendered.